# How does sightly HTML files access global implicit objects in AEM 6

Tags: sightly, aem-6

Unlike inclusion of global.jsp with every component jsp in CQ5, sightly does not include any such dependency. How does it actually access all the global objects. What is the backend process of it. And how sightly code compiles to java??

Answer (score 2):

> how sightly code compiles to java?

Sling sightly API has two bundles to support this, the first step is to compile sightly into [Abstract Syntax Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) (*The Abstract Syntax Tree maps plain Java source code in a tree form. This tree is more convenient and reliable to analyse and modify programmatically than text-based source.*) This is done by [**Apache Sling Scripting Sightly Compiler**](https://github.com/apache/sling/tree/trunk/bundles/scripting/sightly/compiler)

Next is to convert ([transpile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler)) the Abstract Syntax Tree into java source code. This is achieved in bundle [Java Compiler](https://github.com/apache/sling/tree/trunk/bundles/scripting/sightly/java-compiler)

> How does it actually access all the global objects.

To understand this you need to understand how script resolution occurs in Sling and how are resource resolved to scripts which is core to Sling Scripting engine. To understand basics of ScriptEngine look at java docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html), implementation of this is [`SightlyScriptEngine`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly/1.0.2/org/apache/sling/scripting/sightly/impl/engine/SightlyScriptEngine.java)

The way script resolution works is that the resource is adapted to [`DefaultSlingScript`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.sling/org.apache.sling.scripting.core/2.0.32/org/apache/sling/scripting/core/impl/DefaultSlingScript.java#DefaultSlingScript) , this is done by [`SlingScriptAdapterFactory`](https://github.com/apache/sling/blob/trunk/bundles/scripting/core/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/core/impl/SlingScriptAdapterFactory.java).

`SlingScriptAdapterFactory` has references to `BindingsValuesProvider` which is passed to the `DefaultSlingScript`. One of the implementation of `BindingsValuesProvider` is `AEMSightlyBindingsValuesProvider` (you can see this as a service in `/system/console/services`) which provides the default objects.

The `DefaultSlingScript` then responsible for invoking `SightlyScriptEngine` and calling its method `eval` which populates the default objects in binding and then setting this binding as request attribute.